# How to send file with message to Discord with JDA?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am using [JDA](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA) lib to create my discord bot and I encountered a problem: in order to send message with a file, I should use existing message:

```
RestAction<Message> sendFile(File file, Message message)
RestAction<Message> sendFile(File file, String fileName, Message message)
RestAction<Message> sendFile(InputStream data, String fileName, Message message)
```

There is no implementation for sending file with simple string message. So when I'm trying to send file and pass a message to it I've got duplicated message.

So the question is: How to create `Message` with attached file without duplicating the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct method is to use a `MessageBuilder` to format and build a `Message`.

```
Message message = new MessageBuilder().append("My message").build();
textChannel.sendFile(new File("my-file.txt"), message).queue();
```

In JDA, a `Message` object is not necessarily sent yet.

Comment: Oh, this solves my another problem and actually what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can send messages with attached files in one go like this:

```
//channel is a MessageChannel object or similar
channel.sendMessage("message").addFile(new File("path/to/file")).queue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by message editing after posting a file.

```
sendFile(file, null).queue(message -> {
    message.editMessage("Message").queue()
})
```

Comment: This turns something that can be a single request into 2 requests. Additionally `sendFile(file, null)` is ambiguous for latest JDA versions since it conforms to 2 overloads of `sendFile`. Better: `sendMessage("Message").addFile(file).queue()`